# Understanding Output associated with Generators

Tags: python, generator

I am unclear why the output for the code below is 5 rather than 6:

```
def counter_gen(size):
    cur = 1
    while cur <= size:
        yield cur
        cur = cur + 1

c1 = counter_gen(2)
c2 = counter_gen(2)

Total = 0
for x in c1:
    for y in c2:
        Total = Total + x + y # Isn't this 0+1+1 in the first iteration and then 2+2+2 in the 2nd iteration, hence giving 6?

print Total
```

Answer (score 3):

The line `Total = Total + x + y` is executed two times with

- `x==1` and `y==1`: `Total = 0 + 1 + 1` so `Total==2`
- `x==1` and `y==2`: `Total = 2 + 1 + 2` so `Total==5`

then, since `c2` has run its course, the inner loop ends. The outer loop goes in for another iteration with `x==2`, but `c2` has nothing left in it, so the inner for loop is never again entered.